# Problem in storing LocationData in flutter

Tags: flutter, geolocation, location, flutter-dependencies

I am trying getting the location coordinates of user and storing it in variable.

I use the location library from flutter.

But I get this error:

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future'

This is my code

```
Future<LocationData> coords;
double lat, long;
coords = getUserLocationCoordinates();

coords.then((value) => {
          lat = value.latitude,
          long = value.longitude,
        });
```

My getUserLocationCoordinates function

```
getUserLocationCoordinates() async {
  LocationData currentLocation;
  String error;
  Location location = Location();
  try {
    currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
      error = 'please grant permission';
      print(error);
    }
    if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED_NEVER_ASK') {
      error = 'permission denied- please enable it from app settings';
      print(error);
    }
    currentLocation = null;
  }

  return currentLocation;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initialize variables**

```
  String latitude_data;
    String longitude_data;
    bool _serviceEnabled;
```

**Current Location Function**

```
  Future _getLocation() async {
     
        Location location = new Location();
    
        var _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
        _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    
        if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted || !_serviceEnabled) {
          _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
    
          _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
    
        
        } else {
        ///Do something here
        }
    
        LocationData _currentPosition = await location.getLocation();
    
        longitude_data=_currentPosition.longitude.toString();
        latitude_data=_currentPosition.latitude.toString();
    
    ///if you want you can save data to sharedPrefrence   
     SharedPrefrence().setLatitude(_currentPosition.latitude.toString());
        SharedPrefrence().setLongitude(_currentPosition.longitude.toString());
    
      
      
      }
```